# Fourier transform of $ (t^2-1)^n(\operatorname{sign}(t-1)-\operatorname{sign}(t+1)), $

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I have trouble with finding the Fourier Transform of the following function:
$$
(t^2-1)^n(\operatorname{sign}(t-1)-\operatorname{sign}(t+1)),
$$
where $n\in N$.

I know that the answer involve so called generalised sinc function, but I could not get the geneasl constant in front of the $\rm sinc(n, x).$

Thank you.